# Getting the "many" in one-to-many using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have two tables right now, and they form a one-to many relationship. A restaurant table, which maps to multiple inspections. My postgres tables are defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE restaurant (
    id UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    zip VARCHAR(255),
    address VARCHAR(255),
    phone VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE inspection (
    restaurant_id UUID NOT NULL,
    date VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    score int,
    violation VARCHAR(255),
    risk VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (restaurant_id) REFERENCES restaurant(id)
);
```

I'm not sure how to extrapolate all the inspections when I query a restaurant. I am getting all the fields of the restaurant using `resultSet.getString("fieldName")`, but it does not work when I try `resultSet.getString("inspection")`. What is the code I need to get these inspections? This is my current query for getting all restaurants.

```
@Override
    public Optional<Restaurant> selectRestaurantById(UUID id) {
        final String sql = "SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE id = ?"; 
        List<Restaurant> res = jdbcTemplate.query(
                sql, 
                new Object[] {id}, 
                (resultSet, i) -> {
            UUID restaurant_id = UUID.fromString(resultSet.getString("id"));
            String name = resultSet.getString("name");
            String zip = resultSet.getString("zip");
            String address = resultSet.getString("address");
            String phone = resultSet.getString("phone");

            // How do I get an ArrayList of inspections from postgres??
            Restaurant r = new Restaurant(restaurant_id, name, zip, address, phone);
            return r;
        });
        Restaurant found = res.size() > 0 ? res.get(0) : null;
        return Optional.ofNullable(found);
    }
```

Comment: You should join the table to get the all details -
SELECT * FROM restaurant r
INNER JOIN INSPECTION i on r.id = i. restaurant_id WHERE r.id = ?

You will get duplicates restaurant because of one to many relationship on restaurant, so you can either do two times query or handle duplication at first place using join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's got nothing to do with java or JDBC. Start up a basic sql terminal (if you're using postgres, `psql`, on the terminal, that'll do fine) and learn SQL first. There's plenty of tutorials to be found on the web, fortunately :)

queries just produce another table, which you then loop through. `SELECT * FROM foo` just.. gets you that table. And *just* that table, mind. The restaurant table is just that. restaurants. No inspection available anywhere inside it. `FOREIGN KEY` is not magic, and SQL does not truly have the concept of a one to many relationship. At least, not defining like this - they have the concept of joins, which lets you define such relationships ad hoc, between whatever you want. No need for a `FOREIGN KEY` in the definition.

All that `FOREIGN KEY` does, is say to the DB: Can you make an index of this field, and, please fail any transaction that would otherwise write into this table a row where the 'restaurant_id' field has a value that doesn't match the 'id' value of a row in the restaurant table. It's as interesting as `CHECK v > 0` would be. Just a check that's run on commits. That's all.

`SELECT r.*, i.* FROM restaurant r LEFT JOIN inspection i ON i.restaurant_id = r.id WHERE r.id = ?` would do it - that makes a new 'table', so to speak. containing every column from row, and every column from inspection. If a restaurant has 0 inspections, you get 1 row, where every `i.` related field is NULL (because LEFT JOIN; had you written INNER JOIN, you wouldn't get those restaurants at all). For a restaurant with 10 inspections, you'd get 10 rows where all `r.` related fields are repeated.

If that sounds annoying - yeah I can see that. Then run a second query: `SELECT * FROM inspection WHERE restaurant_id = ?`, grab the data, fill your arraylist.

NB: Your tabledef is weird. `score` should probably have a `NOT NULL` restriction.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer! I'm curious, if I had 10 inspections mapped to a restaurant, what would be the best way to access them and put them into a list?

Comment: I can have a list outside of the function and just add them in and then set the get the returned restaurant that list, but I can't do this when I am looking to return a list of restaurants, each with their own list of inspections.

Comment: More generally the idea of 'first I map my tables to objects and then I see what I need' doesn't quite mesh with SQL, which is better at you just querying exactly what you need. So, to answer " if I had 10 inspections mapped to a restaurant, what would be the best way to access them and put them into a list?" I'd have to why you want this data and what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: For example, this model of 'I shall shove _everything_ the database has on the restaurant into one object' is a bad model. Imagine you don't just have inspection but 40 other things. That'd be one heck of a gigantic object. Instead, what do you _NEED_? If it's a web page that is showing violations in your area, then get just that. `SELECT r.name, STRING_AGG(i.violation, ', ') FROM restaurant r INNER JOIN inspection i ON i.restaurant_id = r.id WHERE r.zip IN (?, ?, ?, ?) AND v.score < 6 ORDER BY r.name`.

Comment: I'm working on a backend API, so ideally when a request comes in for restaurant(s), i should be sending over a JSON of all the restaurants, along with their list of inspections

Comment: @George ... seems weird. That's effectively dumping your _entire DB_ into a json to send over. You can do that, of course, but that strongly suggests you have a handful of data (a few hundreds restaurants, perhaps), and none of this matters. It'll all be instant no matter what you do and no matter which indices you have.